# How to fix date inconsistency from external source PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have an issue. The dates from the API come back to me as Feb 4 2016. I have to apply some date modifications for which I need the date in format 02-04-2016. The code works well for the dates returned from the API that are above 9, such as Feb 10 2016 because when I manipulate this, I get it neatly as 02-10-2016. However, the problem is with the dates below 10, such as Feb 4 2016 because these lead to 02-4-2016 which causes an error.

What I would like to know is how I can consistently get the format of 02-04-2016 regardless of dates from API are above 9 or below 10. The following is my code.

```
// Split checkin  date string from API
list($month, $day, $year, $time) = explode(' ', $checkindate); 

// change short month name (e.g Feb) to month number (e.g. 02)
$monthname = $month;
$month = date('m', strtotime($monthname));

// new checkin date in example format 02-20-2016
 $checkin_new = $month.'/'.$day.'/'.$year; // this is the part that causes an error when date returned by API is below 10, for example Feb 4 2016. Other dates above 9 such as Feb 10 2016 work well and don't cause an issue.


// Subtract days
 $newdate = new DateTime($checkin_new ); 
 $subtracteddate = $newdate->modify("-1 day");
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting the date in February use `mktime` function:

```
echo date("M d Y ", mktime( 0,0,0,2, 4, 2016));
echo "<br />";
echo gmdate("M d Y ", mktime( 0,0,0,2, 2, 2016));
```

This would give output:

```
Feb 04 2016
Feb 01 2016
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

mYou can simply ask PHP to do all the job at once:

```
$formatted_date = date('m-d-Y', strtotime($chekindate));
```

Comment: Thanks for comments both. Tried your solutions, but date leads to 12-31-1969.

Comment: @mush It works fine for me (proof: try `echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime('Feb 4 2016'));`). So you'd check your `$checkindate` content.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the function `strtotime` directly:

```
echo date('m-d-Y', strtotime('Feb 4 2016'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to think of a solution. May not be ideal, but it works.

Basically, the problem was that I needed an added 0 before for example 4 when the day is below 10. Days above 9 work well already. So I wrote a simple if statement and concatenated it in the code. Updated parts are in bold

```
// Split checkin  date string from API
list($month, $day, $year, $time) = explode(' ', $checkindate); 

// if day is below 9, give var patchday value 0. Otherwise leave it empty
**if ($day < 10) { $patchday = "0"; } else { $patchday = ""; };**

// change short month name (e.g Feb) to month number (e.g. 02)
$monthname = $month;
$month = date('m', strtotime($monthname));

// new checkin date in example format 02-20-2016
 $checkin_new = $month.'/'.**$patchday**.$day.'/'.$year;

// Subtract days
 $newdate = new DateTime($checkin_new ); 
 $subtracteddate = $newdate->modify("-1 day");
```

Answer (score 0):

use DateTime object which can accept many formats

```
echo (new DateTime('Feb 4 2016'))->format('m-d-Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method with the month accepted without leading zeros, a three letter month, and spaces in between, by using `F j Y` like this;

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j Y', $checkindate);
```

and then format it, like this;

```
$formatteddate = $date->format('m-d-Y');
```

If the time is also returned from the API, then you just need to add it to your `createFromFormat` string in the correct format (which you can find on the docs page) such as `H:i:s`;

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('F j Y H:i:s', $checkindate);
```

Comment: Hi @mush if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.